# Stop page jump but still go to href

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, href

I've searched a lot through your answers, but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

Now, my situation is this:

I have a div, with id="modal", that is hided and showed simply adding css property with jquery.

Inside "modal" there are more divs horizontally positioned, to make a slide, and each div has an id.

Outside "modal", I have a menu in which each link points to some div of the slider.

Everything works properly, each div is showed when it's called, but my problem is that every time I click on a link and the "modal" is showed, the page jumps to the bottom or scrolls down.

I tried with event.preventDefault(), but it blocks the selection of the slider divs.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Ps: I have this problem with every browser except with Firefox.

To help understand this is the jQuery:

```
function Show() {
    $('.modal').css('display', 'block');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
};

function Hide() {
    $('.modal').css('display', 'none');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
};

function Next() {
    $('#main-wrap').animate({scrollLeft: '+=800'}, 1000);
};

function Previous() {
    $('#main-wrap').animate({scrollLeft: '-=800'}, 1000);
};
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="main-modal">
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <a id="close" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="Hide()">Close</a>
    <a id="next" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="Next()">Next</a>
    <a id="previous" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="Previous()">Previous</a>

    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper-div" id="Art1">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-div" id="Art2">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-div" id="Art3">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-div" id="Art4">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-div" id="Art5">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="overlay" class="modal">
</div>
</div>

   <div class="container">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#Art1" onClick="Show()">Valerio Adami</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Art2" onClick="Show()">Rodolfo Aricò</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Art3" onClick="Show()">Mario Bionda</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Art4" onClick="Show()">Remo Brindisi</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Art5" onClick="Show()">Carmelo Cappello</a></li>
     </ol>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not inline script
2. do not use the javascript protocol in hrefs
3. return false or preventDefault from the event handler
4. use class names instead of having a function per type of click

Number 3:

```
$(function() {
  $("#close").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Hide();
  });
});
```

using

```
 <a id="close" href="#">Close</a>
```

Better than hide and show:

```
$(function() {
  $("#toggle").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal').toggle();
  });
});
```

using

```
 <a id="toggle" href="#">Toggle</a>
```

Comment: ok for the close script and for don't use inline script and javascript protocol in href. But, like I said, if I use preventDefault() or return false, I can't reach the exact div I want, because it continues to open the first. I want to visit the href but stop the page jumping

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. If you do not want all modal divs to open, use the ID to open the one you want. If you use .modal both of them will open

Comment: all the div are inside the modal, that is smaller, so when the modal is opened only one div at a time is visible. Now I want that when you click on Link1 the modal is opened with Div1 visible, when u click on Link3, the modal is opened with Div 3 visible. This is the link to the section of the site I'm talking: http://carte-scoperte.com/alex/index.html#artisti
At the moment is with the page jump problem, so u can see what I mean, I hope u can understand me now ;)

Comment: What should I see when I click an artist and what is wrong with what i see?

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot to upload the file modified. So, first of all, only the first 5 artist on the left are set, and each one open the modal, with the corresponding div visible. The problem is that when the modal is opened the page jumps to the bottom or scrolls down a bit